# What about the installation process in gradle to run the project?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I didn't know how to use the gradle.I am downloaded the gradle in this link. https://www.gradle.org/downloads

Right now I am using the Android eclipse.Let me know gradle would be used in Android eclipse or Android Studio?

What about the installation process in gradle to run the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android studio is flexible Gradle-based build system. It contains gradle by default. See this: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

For eclipse you can use plugin. Here's a link: http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html